# saving QML image

Tags: qt, qml

How can I save QML Image into phone memory ??

also if saving the image was applicable , I have this case which I need to add some text to the image (we can imagine it as we have a transparent image[that hold the text] and put it over the second image , so finally we have one image  that we can save it into phone memory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not from `Image` directly. `QDeclarativeImage` has `pixmap`, `setPixmap` and `pixmapChange` methods, but for some reason there is no property declared. So you cannot use it fom qml. Unfortunately it cannot be used from C++ either - it is a private calsss.

What you can do is paint graphics item to your pixmap and save it to file.

```
class Capturer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Capturer(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void save(QDeclarativeItem *obj);
};

void Capturer::save(QDeclarativeItem *item)
{
    QPixmap pix(item->width(), item->height());
    QPainter painter(&pix);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem option;
    item->paint(&painter, &option, NULL);
    pix.save("/path/to/output.png");
}
```

Register "capturer" context variable:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    Capturer capturer;
    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("capturer", &capturer);
    // ...
}
```

And use it in your qml:

```
Rectangle {
    // ...
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "/path/to/your/source"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            capturer.save(img)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dear , It works :) . Now I search about how to merge 2 images in Qt , can you help me ?

Comment: how do overlay/merge 2 `QQuickItem`s & save it to an image ?

Answer (score 7):

With Qt 5.4+ you can do it straight from your Qml with:
[grabToImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method)