# Transport QML Image via Bridge

Tags: qt, qml, pyside6

I have at the moment a simple PySide6 app which uses `qml` for image capturing. I want to transport the image to our app but cannot figure out how. I am not sure, if [saving QML image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011391/saving-qml-image) is an attempt in the right direction.

### My PySide App

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QImage
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, QmlElement


QML_IMPORT_NAME = "io.qt.textproperties"
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1


@QmlElement
class Bridge(QObject):
    @Slot(QImage)
    def capture(self, preview):
        # Do something with the preview
        print(type(preview))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    # Get the path of the current directory, and then add the name
    # of the QML file, to load it.
    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "simpleCam.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

### MY QML File

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia

import io.qt.textproperties


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainFrame
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Cam Test")
    
    Bridge {
        id: bridge
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 640
        height: 400
       
        MediaDevices {
            id: mediaDevices
        }

        CaptureSession {
            imageCapture: ImageCapture {
                id: capture
            }
            camera: Camera {
                id: camera                
            }
            videoOutput: output
        }

        VideoOutput {
            id: output
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Button {
            id: startCamButton
            text: "Start Cam"
            anchors.top: output.bottom
            anchors.left: output.left
            onClicked: {
                camera.start()
                camImage.opacity = 0
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: takePicButton
            text: "take pic"
            anchors.top: output.bottom
            anchors.left: startCamButton.right
            onClicked: {
                capture.capture()
                camImage.opacity = 1
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: camImage
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: capture.preview
        }
    }
}
```

### The Result

[image]

### What is missing?

In the `Button` with `id: takePicButton` I want to transport the image to the PySide6 Bridge. If I add to the`onClicked` Signal `bridge.capture(capture.preview)` I got the Error:

```bash
TypeError: Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is not allowed.`
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `imageCaptured` signal.

Change:

```
imageCapture: ImageCapture {
    id: capture
}
```

To:

```
imageCapture: ImageCapture {
    id: capture
    onImageCaptured: function(req_id, preview){bridge.capture(req_id, preview)}
}
```

And change in main.py:

```py
@Slot(QImage)
def capture(self, preview):
    # Do something with the preview
    print(type(preview))
```

To:

```py
@Slot(int, QImage)
def capture(self,req_id, preview):
    print(req_id)
    print(type(preview))
```

---

Working example [here](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/QtQuick/Image-capture).
You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439554/save-qml-image-inside-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer for other use cases.

Comment: Works like expected. This is quite obfuscated in the documentation.